# how to wipe cache android from adb terminal?

Tags: android

I'm using an android system builded with yocto and I do often the updates of the apps with adb from linux, but after a certain quantity of updates the partition /dev/block/mmcblk2p3 remain full, and I can't continue to do others updates.
How can I wipe the cache or clean it. using adb commands?

Comment: Questions about topics other than development or programming, but related to Android, are not on-topic for Stack Overflow, but **may** be on-topic at https://android.stackexchange.com (and you're more likely to get a good answer there). Please review [what types of questions are on-topic in that community](//android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting there to ensure that your question is on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

you can try  `adb shell su -c "rm -rf /data/data/<app's package>/cache/*"`

if your application is compiled with a debug key, you can also use run-as command in adb's shell. So it would look like this: `adb shell run-as <app's package> rm -rf /data/data/<app's package>/cache/*` This method does not require root.
or below requires root

```
rm -r /data/dalvik-cache
rm -r /cache/dalvik-cache
```

Comment: `Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/block/mmcblk2p3 1.4G  1.1G  336M  78% /
tmpfs                487M  608K  487M   1% /dev
tmpfs                487M     0  487M   0% /mnt
tmpfs                487M     0  487M   0% /apex
/dev/block/mmcblk2p8 1.6G  202M  1.4G  12% /product
/dev/block/mmcblk2p7 472M   55M  418M  12% /vendor
/dev/block/mmcblk2p9 3.0G   78M  2.9G   3% /data
/data/media          3.0G   78M  2.9G   3% /mnt/runtime/default/emulated`

Answer (score 0):

adb shell run-as <app's package> rm -rf /data/data/<app's package>/cache/*

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the my problem.

before sending the update files you need to kill the app process.

```
 killall my_app_name_process
```

then

```
 push files like this
```

adb push "my_app_name_process" /my_path/my_app_name_process

```
 adb shell pm clear com.my_app.vow
```